# Define variable within docker-compose's config yaml file

Tags: docker-compose, ubuntu-18.04, ubuntu-22.04

## Question

Is there a way to define a variable within a docker-compose's config yaml file?

#### My usecase FYI

Using ["extends" (docker.com)](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#extending-services) I'm thinking to use a base yaml and configure it from many child yaml files by passing a variable.

One limitation is that I cannot make the operational commands complicated at all (intended users are not developers) so I want the command to be a single-line, and cannot be too long. So defining variable in the operation command (e.g. `docker-compose -f ... up` is fine, but adding `VAR=foo` at the beginning of it is too long and complicated for me, particularly I might want to define multiple variables).

## What I've tried but didn't work

So far I thought of using docker-compose's environment variable features (note that I don't care if the variable I want to set is environment variable or something else. I just gave a try as the features are already there).

#### NG: Using "environment"

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  service_a:
    image: ubuntu:focal
    environment:
      ENV_A: "env_a"
    command: >
      /bin/bash -c "echo In docker container: $ENV_A"
```

Then have `env_a`, the content of `ENV_A`, printed. But it didn't get printed:

```
$ docker-compose -f a.yaml up
WARNING: The ENV_A variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
:
service_a_1  | In docker container:
tmp_service_a_1 exited with code 0
```

#### NG: Using "env_file"

```
$ cat a.env 
ENV_A=env_a
```

```
$ cat b.yaml
version: '3.3'
services:
  service_b:
    image: ubuntu:focal
    env_file: ./a.env
    command: >
      /bin/bash -c "echo In docker container: $ENV_A"
```

Result: NG.

```
$ docker-compose -f b.yaml up
WARNING: The ENV_A variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
:
service_b_1  | In docker container:
```

### Operation environment

```
$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
:
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `extends` is not supported on compose 3.x. This is at [the top of the link you sent](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#extending-services). So you may not want to rely on that.

As for environment variables, only variables set in the `.env` file are available to compose. Variables set in `env_file` or `environment` settings within the compose file will be passed into the container, but will NOT be available for use in compose itself.

You're asking compose to interpolate `$ENV_A`, but you haven't set it on the command line (like you described at the top, `VAR=foo docker...`) or in the `.env`, so it can't find a value.

More in [this thread on GitHub](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4189#issuecomment-268265047).